# How many connections are possible between $n$ points, with a maximum distance of $m$?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How many connections are possible between $n$ points, with a maximum distance of $m$? I really don't know about the technical terms of combinatorics, but here the distance is defined as how many unit-length it covers when joining another point. So when a point joins an adjacent point, the distance will be 1. When it joins a point situated just after it's adjacent point, then the distance will be 2, so on.

And also the points are all in a line, not scattered around and the distance between each points are 1. So for $n$ points and a maximum distance the points are allowed $m$, how many connections are possible?
So the points are allowed to go 1,2,...m.

Comment: Clarify if distance is the min length of paths between two points else the distance between two points with intermediate points may be infinite or not unique for any given two nodes

Comment: It's the minimum

Comment: So with like 5 points and max distance of 3. The points can be of distance 1,2,3.

Answer (score 2):

If $n \leq m$, then every pair of points can be connected, so the answer is
$$
\binom{n}{2} = \frac{n^2 - n}{2}.
$$
If $n > m$, then maybe not every pair of points can be connected. In this case, split the points into the first $m$ points, and the $n-m$ points afterwards. The first $m$ points are all pairwise connected, for a total of $(m^2 - m)/2$ connections. Meanwhile, all points after those first $m$, which are $n - m$ in total, each have connections to $m$ points before them. This counts all connections precisely once, for a total of
$$
(m^2 - m)/2 + m(n-m) = \frac{2mn - m^2 - m}{2}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

There are $n-1$ pairs of points with distance $1$, $n-2$ pairs with distance $2$, and so on up to $n-m$ pairs with distance $m$. The total number of valid connections is the sum of these numbers: $$\begin{align}\sum_{i=n-m}^{n-1}i&=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i-\sum_{i=1}^{n-m-1}i\\&=\binom n2-\binom {n-m}2\end{align}$$
This can also be expressed as $$\frac{m(2n-m-1)}{2}$$ which is equivalent to the earlier answer.